# Creating Buttons with Images on Microsoft Band

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I've been trying the new **Microsoft Band SDK**, especially the support for buttons (finally), but got stuck on trying to create **buttons with images** on top. Tried what's described in the oficila SDK doc (*[page 29, topic 2.7.2.1 - Negative Margins][1]*), that states that, **defining margins with a negative value for the second child**, makes them item on top (in this case an image/icon on top of a button), thus making an image button.

The result I'm getting are either:

1. A button with an image under it
2. An image over the button, but making the button non clickable (changing the order of the items inside the Panel).

Has anyone tried this?

Been banging my head for a few days with this.

Help would be much apreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue Daniel. Currently the button + overlapping icon scenario will not work. A future software release will address this problem.

Note that the z-order of child elements of a container is topmost (first child) to bottom (last child). So, the order of elements in the FlowPanel would need to be {icon, button} such that the icon gets rendered on top of the button. The example in the SDK doc is incorrect in that it specifies the order as {button, icon}. However, while fixing the order is a necessary step to getting the scenario to work, it alone is not sufficient, the aforementioned future software release will be required as well.